# SQL Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm getting keyword input in a textbox like test,check,..etc.I insert those keyword as individual rows in my database on checking if it exists,if exists update or else insert it.This keywordid and item that represents to this id should be inserted into bridge table.On inserting existing keyword it throws errors:

> `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`
>
> `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'KeywordId', table 'dbo.Keywordsitems'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.`

I'm using the below stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertKeywords] 
(
  @keywordName nvarchar(256),
  @itemid uniqueidentifier
)
AS
begin
  declare 
    @itemid uniqueidentifier,
    @keywordid uniqueidentifier,
    @id uniqueidentifier;
  declare @keyworddata table (keywordid uniqueidentifier);

  set @id = (select KeywordId  from keywords where KeyName=@keywordName)
  set @itemid =(select itemId from Items where ItemID = @itemid);

  if not exists(select keyname from keywords where KeyName = @keywordName)
  begin
    insert into Keywords(KeywordId,KeyName)
    output inserted.KeywordId into @keyworddata(keywordid)
    values (newid(),@keywordName);

    select @keywordid = keywordid from @keyworddata;

    insert into Keywordsitems(KeywordId,ItemId)
    values (@keywordid,@itemid);
  end
  else
  begin
    update keywords set KeyName=@keywordName where KeywordName= @keywordName;
    insert into KeywordsResources(KeywordId,itemId) values (@id,@itemid);       
  end
end
```

Comment: If you have multiple rows with the same `KeyName` or `ItemID`, which one do you want? Seems like you have a constraint missing somewhere.

Comment: I need to check for same keywordname if exists update if not insert it.I need the checking on my keywords table which just have keywordid ,keywordname column.Once the update or insert is done in keywords table later i need to insert onto the bridge table is where i've to insert both keywordid and itemid

Comment: Your code is vary hard to follow. Your `@itemid` switches from being an `@itemid` to a `@databaseid`? Why? If there is more than one `resourcedatabaseId` for a specific item, what do you want to do? Currently (with the fix supplied below) it's going to pick an arbitrary database id, not loop through all of them. `@itemid` doesn't magically become an array...

Comment: Also how is your stored procedure possibly accepting a parameter named `@itemid` and then also declaring a variable with the same name? And can you explain the difference between `KeyName` and `KeywordName`? And you're really calling this stored procedure once for every keyword in your comma-separated list? Your poor database server...

Comment: Use proper indenting to format that code so we can SEE it without squinting and mental gymnastics!

Comment: Aaron Bertrand : I've formatted my code to some extent and also the resourcedatabaseid is a mistake it's itemid and i've changes to it.sorry for the confusion

Comment: What about KeyName and KeywordName? Why do you seem to be setting both of those to the same, redundant string value?

Comment: @AndriyM good edit. I was trying to find the line that caused the horizontal scrollbar and gave up.

Comment: The nested select is before the update / insert. So duplicate data already exists.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thanks. I also removed a pair of `begin`/`end` as apparently redundant, but now it strikes me there might be a missing `if` condition corresponding to them (possibly checking for `@id` and `@itemid` to be not NULL). I might be reading too much into it, though.

Comment: I can't follow this, sorry, it's a disaster. KeyName vs. KeywordName, if the keyword doesn't exist you insert into keywordsitems, if it does exist you insert into keywordsresources (without checking if it's already there). Please clean up the query so that it makes sense. Right now it's actually killing brain cells.

Comment: "Oh, woe is me, I don't want to die! Bill just kicked the bucket and I can't find Gertie and I'm so afraid I'll be next. Ohmigosh... it's. It's coming. Ohhh noes!!! Noooooooo! I never got to tell my mo— AIEEEEEEE [splat]" - @Aaron's brain cell #2147483647

Answer (score 0):

You can use TOP 1 to resolve this.

E.g.,

```
...
set @id = (select top 1 KeywordId  from keywords where KeyName=@keywordName)
set @itemid =(select top 1 resourcedatabaseId from Items where ItemID = @itemid); 
...
```

Comment: only if you have no reason to care which of the two you get.

Comment: @HLGEM: Could you please explain it.I din't get your point.I may be wrong with my approach.Just looking for a better code to handle this.

Comment: This will randomly pick one of the values, but often you want a specific one (like the  newest or the oldest, etc and you need to do something else to pick that one).

Comment: Solved it,it's my mistake.I had more than one id for a keyname which caused the confusion and also made some changes to my sp by removing set @id = (select top 1 KeywordId  from keywords where KeyName=@keywordName).thanks to all for the help.